# Does an irreducible operator generate a nuclear $C^{*}$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**Definition** : An operator $T \in B(H)$ is **irreducible** ([Halmos 1968](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-15/issue-2/Irreducible-operators/10.1307/mmj/1028999975.full)) if its commutant $\{ T\}'$ does not contain projections other than $0$ and $I$  (i.e., $T \ne T_{1} \oplus T_{2}$, or equivalently,  $\{T,T^{*}\}''=B(H)$).

**Definition** : A $C^{*}$-algebra  $\mathcal{A}$ is **[nuclear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_C*-algebra)** if and only if its [enveloping von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enveloping_von_Neumann_algebra) $\pi_{U}(\mathcal{A})''$ (with $\pi_{U}$ its [universal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark%E2%80%93Segal_construction#States_and_representations))  is [hyperfinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Amenable_von_Neumann_algebras).

Let $T \in B(H)$ be an irreducible operator, and let $\mathcal{A} = C^{*}(T)$.   Now $W^{*}(T) = \mathcal{A}''$ is the von Neumann algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ (*a priori*, it's not its enveloping von Neumann algebra).   Now by definition of irreducibility, $W^{*}(T) = B(H)$, which is the **hyperfinite** $I_{\infty}$ factor. Is $\pi_{U}(\mathcal{A})''$ also hyperfinite ?

> Does an irreducible operator generate a nuclear $C^{*}$-algebra ?

If no, is it nevertheless an [exact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_C*-algebra) $C^{*}$-algebra ?
**Remark**: All nuclear $C^{*}$-algebras and their $C^{*}$-subalgebras are exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the post: [Does an irreducible operator generate an exact $C^{∗}$-algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455949/does-an-irreducible-operator-generate-an-exact-c-algebra).

C. Eckhardt answered "no" by giving some simple, singly generated and non-exact $C^{*}$-algebras.
By simplicity, their irreducible representations are faithful.

So, there are irreducible operators $T \in B(H)$ with $C^{*}(T)$ non-exact (and a fortiori non-nuclear).